# How to hide widget with animation when Scroll down using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem as with two `Icons Buttons` as the below image:

[image: Icons Buttons]

The problem here when I scroll down till another widget appear for example a map or a Graph the `Icons Buttons` looks like the below image:

[image: result]

So I got an idea is to hide those button when scroll down and show them again when scroll app with an animation, but I don't know how to do this..

This the below related Code:

```
return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 85,
                        left: 10,
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Sim information',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          DataTable(
                            headingRowHeight: 20,
                            columnSpacing: 83,
                            dataRowHeight: double.parse('20'),
                            columns: [
                              DataColumn(
                                  label: Text(
                                'Sim operator',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              )),
                              DataColumn(
                                label: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      simInfo.operator == null
                                          ? ' '
                                          : simInfo.operator,
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                            rows: [
                              DataRow(cells: [
                                DataCell(Row(
                                    Text('ICCID'),
                                  ],
                                )),
                                DataCell(
                                    Text(simInfo == null ? '' : simInfo.iccid)),
                              ]),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    //Network provider
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 20,
                        left: 10,
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Network Provider',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          DataTable(
                            headingRowHeight: 20,
                            columnSpacing: 120,
                            dataRowHeight: double.parse('20'),
                            columns: [
                              DataColumn(
                                  label: Text(
                                'Operator',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              )),
                              DataColumn(
                                label: Text(
                                  simInfo == null ? '' : simInfo.operator,
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                            rows: [
                              DataRow(cells: [
                                DataCell(Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text('MCC'),
                                  ],
                                )),
                                DataCell(
                                  Text(simInfo == null
                                      ? ''
                                      : simInfo.mcc.toString()),
                                ),
                              ]),
                              DataRow(cells: [
                                DataCell(Text('MNC')),
                                DataCell(
                                  Text(simInfo == null
                                      ? ''
                                      : simInfo.mnc.toString()),
                                ),
                              ]),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    //Serving Cell
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 20,
                        left: 10,
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Serving Cell',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          DataTable(
                              columnSpacing: 120,
                              headingRowHeight: 20,
                              dataRowHeight: double.parse('20'),
                              columns: [
                                DataColumn(
                                    label: Text(
                                  'Data type',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                )),
                                DataColumn(
                                  label: Text(
                                    _baseStation == null
                                        ? ''
                                        : _baseStation.type.toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                              rows: [
                                DataRow(cells: [
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text('TYPE'),
                                  ),
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text(_baseStation.type.toString()),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                                DataRow(cells: [
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text('CId'),
                                  ),
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text(_baseStation.cid.toString()),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                                DataRow(cells: [
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text('TAC'),
                                  ),
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text(_baseStation == null
                                        ? ''
                                        : _baseStation.tac.toString()),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                                DataRow(cells: [
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text('PCI'),
                                  ),
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text(_baseStation.bsicPscPci.toString()),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                                DataRow(cells: [
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text('LAC'),
                                  ),
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text(_baseStation.lac.toString()),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                                DataRow(cells: [
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text('MCC'),
                                  ),
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text(_baseStation.mcc.toString()),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                                DataRow(cells: [
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text('MNC'),
                                  ),
                                  DataCell(
                                    Text(_baseStation.mnc.toString()),
                                  ),
                                ]),
                              ]),
                          if (_baseStation.type == 'GSM')
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 0,
                              ),
                              child: GSMStationFields(_baseStation),
                            ),
                          if (_baseStation.type == 'LTE')
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 0,
                              ),
                              child: LTEStationFields(_baseStation),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: SignalStrengthGraph(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (activeSlotsSize > 1)
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: RadioBtnSim(changeSlot),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

and this is my widget part I call which have the problem:

```
Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: SignalStrengthGraph(),
                    ),
```

So is there's any other solution or idea to solve this issue?

I hope this would be clear enough and some one give me good reccomendation :)..

Answer (score 8):

You can use `AnimatedContainer()`
For example:

```
var iconContainerHeight = 55.00;

AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            height: _bottomBarHeight,
            child: YOUR_CONTAINER WITCH ICONS)

void _scrollListener() {
    if (_controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      if (iconContainerHeight != 0)
        setState(() {
          iconContainerHeight = 0;
        });
    }
    if (_controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward) {
      if (iconContainerHeight == 0)
        setState(() {
          iconContainerHeight = 55;
        });
    }
  }
```

You remember:

```
initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
}
```

and:

```
 dispose() {
    _controller.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    }
```

Comment: I think this answer is the best one but how can I use this code to my code, and what the `_controller` referred to?

Comment: First - you must declared `ScrollController _controller;` in you class where you want use this.
Two - you should declare `_controller = ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);` in `initState()`

next: you have to write function `_scrollListener()`

Comment: Superb answer. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a ScrollController. With it, your code runs every time the user scrolls. There, you can keep track of the current scroll offset and when it's larger than the previous value that you saved, you can make those buttons invisible.

This article explains it quite well: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Visibility` widget with animation and provide time for the visibility gone animation.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer but how can I use the Visibility widget related to my code :D

Comment: just wrap it around the widget you want to disappear.

Comment: I tried this solution but doesn't work it invisible the `IconButton` without scrolling

Comment: You need to combine animation with visibility widget.